# Can't boot after recovering backup

Tags: backup, encryption, init

I installed Xubuntu 10.10 on a 16 GB pendrive with full disk encryption using the alternate installer. The installation process was quite time consuming so I made a backup booting from the standard live CD with something along these lines

```
dd if=/dev/sdb conv=noerror,sync | pv | gzip -c -9 > foobar.img.gz
```

The pendrive booted fine for a couple of days and BTW it was quite good performance-wise, but I decided to scrape it off and start from the backup, so I run

```
gunzip -c foobar.img.gz | pv | dd of=/dev/sdb conv=sync,noerror
```

Now upon boot I am getting

```
error: hd0,msdos1 write error.
```

After a while the login screen appears:

```
Unlocking the disk /dev/disk/by-uuid/58a8... (sdb5_crypt)
Enter passphrase:
```

So I enter it, get the OK message

```
cryptsetup: sdb5_crypt set up successfully
```

only to get the following prompt

```
No init found. Try passing init= bootarg.

BusyBox v1.15.3 (Ubuntu 1:1.15.3-1ubuntu5) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of buil-in commands.

(initramfs)
```

How to fix it? Is it possible to do backups of encrypted systems this way or do I have to use different tools for backup operating on the filesystem level for example?

Answer (score 2):

check your grub config and make sure it properly references the location of the init image.

this:error: hd0,msdos1 write error.  makes me think partitions either aren't set up right or that a flag is set that declares an ext partition as msdos.  dos partitions don't play nicely with ext permissions...

a backup in the fashion you describe should have worked imho.

i have successfully done it without the convo= args and pv, but you don't get any idea of the progress.  i typically do it right before bed and get up with an image copied.

Answer (score 0):

It's incognitus here, I cleared my previous browser cookie. :/

I tried looking into grub configuration, but as I preferred having working OS more quickly than learning even more about the boot process this time, I decided to repartition the drive and run the installer from scratch once again. It didn't work out. This time the installer gave me this message

```
[!!] Partition disks
Input/output error during write on /dev/sdb
ERROR!!!

Retry
Ignore
Cancel 

<Go Back>
```

So I then tried zeroing the device booting from the standard live CD

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb
```

which didn't give me any error messages, but gparted couldn't modify its partition structure and the boot and crypt partitions were still there as if untouched.

So I tried also shred

```
shred -n1 -v -z /dev/sdb
```

this time getting errors

```
shred: /dev/sdb: pass 1/2 (random)...
shred: /dev/sdb: pass 1/2 (random)...82MiB/15GiB 0%
shred: /dev/sdb: fdatasync failed: Input/output error
shred: /dev/sdb: pass 1/2 (random)...156MiB/15GiB 1%
shred: /dev/sdb: fdatasync failed: Input/output error
...
```

I managed to figure that somewhere in the process my pendrive become unwritable (I admit some kernel related problems when installing virtualbox-ose dependencies - but I didn't think it would be as serious) and making a USB drive read-only happened to some people on the Internet as well. However dmesg is saying "Write Protect is off". The exact model is Emtec S400EM 16 GB http://www.emtec-international.com/en/produit.php?categorie=STMOB&gamme=CLES%20USB&ss_gamme=S400%20EM and I emailed their support about what sectors I might have overwritten or what might be the issue with the pendrive turning read-only. I am waiting for their response. It's got 5 years warranty and although their packaging mentions only "Windows Vista" and presumes using factory default NTFS I wonder what their response might be.

Thanks for tips anyway!

Comment: My problems might also be related to U3 (http://www.emtec-international.com/en/annexes/u3_technologie.php?categorie=STMOB), but I didn't quite succeed with u3-tool http://u3-tool.sourceforge.net/.